# Array merge if key not exists

Tags: php, arrays

I tried merging two arrays if the key is not exists in the array but I cannot accomplish this. How can i do? This is what I have tried:

```
  array (size=3)  // name of the array $exchange
  'purchase' => string '1' (length=1)
  'agriculture' => string '1' (length=1)

 array (size=6)  // name of the array $fixed
  'purchase' => string '0' (length=1)
  'ICT' => string '0' (length=1)
  'agriculture' => string '0' (length=1)
  'entertainment' => string '0' (length=1)
  'goods and service' => string '0' (length=1)
  'other' => string '0' (length=1)

   foreach($fixed as $keys=>$values){

    if(!in_array($values, $exchange, true)){

       array_push($exchange, $keys);
    }
   }
```

I get this result:

```
 array (size=7)
 'ICT' => string '1' (length=1)
 0 => string 'purchase' (length=8)
 1 => string 'ICT' (length=3)
 2 => string 'agriculture' (length=11)
 3 => string 'entertainment' (length=13)
 4 => string 'goods and service' (length=17)
 5 => string 'other' (length=5)
```

But I want:

```
 array (size=7)
 'ICT' => string '1' (length=1)
 'purchase' => string '0' (length=8)
 'agriculture' => string '0' (length=11)
 'entertainment' => string '0' (length=13)
 'goods and service' => string '0' (length=17)
 'other' => string '0' (length=5)
```

Comment: First array shows ``size=3`` but you only copy/pasted 2 items... please fix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it in several ways depending the result you desire:

```
foreach($fixed as $key=>$values){
    if(!isset($exchange[$key])){
        $exchange[$key]=values;
    }
}
```

or

```
$exchange += $fixed;
```

or

```
$exchange = array_merge($fixed,$exchange);
```

Comment: You need to be careful using `array_merge` with non-numeric keys. The values in a later argument will overwrite any values in an earlier argument. For this reason, you probably want to flip the arguments in your answer, as any keys that already exist in `$exchange` will be overwritten with the default values in `$fixed`.

Comment: Third option you mentioned is invalid solution, array_merge also updates existing keys. First variant is multiple lines and seems ugly. Hovewer second one is the best solution, it does what user mentioned in title.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
foreach ($fixed as $keys => $values) {
    if (! array_key_exists($keys, $exchange)) {
        $exchange[$keys] = $values;
    }
}
```

It checks if the key `$keys` does not already exists in `$exchange` and adds it together with its value (`$values`).

Or you can simply replace the entire `foreach()` block with:

```
$exchange = $exchange + $fixed;
```

The addition `$exchange + $fixed` adds to `$exchange` the keys (and their values) that are in `$fixed` but are not in `$exchange`. The combined array is then stored in `$exchange`.

Read also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28022692/4265352). It explains where your code is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems with this:

1. `in_array` will search the *values* of the given array, not the keys, so in this case you just end up checking if the value "0" exists in the array `$variable`. I assume instead you wanted to check if the key already exists.
2. `array_push` pushes a new *value* into the next available key.

What you need is to check if a key exists, and if not, add it with the existing value. Try this instead:

```
for($fixed as $key=>$value)
{
    if(!isset($exchange[$key])) // Check if the key exists
    {
        $exchange[$key] = $value; // Add the new key -> value pair.
    }
}
```

Comment: `array_key_exists($key, $exchange)` is better than `isset($exchange[$key])`. Maybe `$exchange[$key]` is `NULL` and the OP wants it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `array_merge` (http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php)

```
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```